# Is there a way to grab associated data from three different tables and display them?

Tags: mysql

I have four tables, three of which I need data from, as well as a fourth that stores how this data is associated. When running my query, I'm getting the wrong output and it seems like I'm not linking things up correctly, but I'm unsure as to how to do so. How do I link my joins to get the output I'm looking for?

So far, I've used

```
SELECT c.class, p.name, s.specialization
FROM players_classes pc
JOIN players p ON p.player_id=pc.player_id
JOIN classes c ON c.class_id=pc.class_id
JOIN specialization s ON s.spec_id=pc.spec_id
```

which references

```
CREATE TABLE players(
player_id INT UNSIGNED auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20)
)...;
CREATE TABLE classes(
class_id INT UNSIGNED auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
class VARCHAR(20)
)...;
CREATE TABLE specializations(
spec_id INT UNSIGNED auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
class_id INT UNSIGNED,
specialization VARCHAR(20)
)...;
```

but I'd like to be using this table in some way to display the information correctly linked, I'm just unsure how to do so:

```
CREATE TABLE players_classes(
pc_id INT UNSIGNED auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY(class_id) REFERENCES classes(class_id),
FOREIGN KEY(player_id) REFERENCES players(player_id),
FOREIGN KEY(spec_id) REFERENCES specializations(spec_id)
)...;
```

I'm expecting to be able to grab a player's name as well as their associated class and specialization, actual results are showing the values associated with 1/1/1 for each id, and so on and so forth.

edit: the data from players_classes is as follows

```
pc_id | class_id | player_id | spec_id |
   1          3           1         8
   2         12           2        35
   3          2           3         6
etc.
```

therefore the expected result from this is

```
class    |   name      |   spec
paladin    seranul      holypa
hunter     contherious  marksmanship
priest     unicorns     holypr
```

I am instead getting

```
class      |        name       |    spec
warlock       Affliction         Affliction
warlock       Grireaver          Demonology
warlock       Affliction         Demonology
```

and so on throughout the table, listing combinations that do not exist within my players_classes table

specializations table

```
+---------+----------+----------------+
| spec_id | class_id | specialization |
+---------+----------+----------------+
|       1 |        1 | Affliction     |
|       2 |        1 | Destruction    |
|       3 |        1 | Demonology     |
|       4 |        2 | Shadow         |
|       5 |        2 | Discipline     |
|       6 |        2 | HolyPr         |
|       7 |        3 | Retribution    |
|       8 |        3 | HolyPa         |
|       9 |        3 | ProtectionPa   |
|      10 |        4 | ProtectionWa   |
|      11 |        4 | Arms           |
|      12 |        4 | Fury           |
|      13 |        5 | FrostMa        |
|      14 |        5 | Fire           |
|      15 |        5 | Arcane         |
|      16 |        6 | vengeance      |
|      17 |        6 | havoc          |
|      18 |        7 | guardian       |
|      19 |        7 | balance        |
|      20 |        7 | feral          |
|      21 |        7 | restorationDr  |
|      22 |        8 | elemental      |
|      23 |        8 | enhance        |
|      24 |        8 | restorationSh  |
|      25 |        9 | frostDk        |
|      26 |        9 | blood          |
|      27 |        9 | unholy         |
|      28 |       10 | outlaw         |
|      29 |       10 | assassin       |
|      30 |       10 | subtlety       |
|      31 |       11 | brewmaster     |
|      32 |       11 | windwalker     |
|      33 |       11 | mistweaver     |
|      34 |       12 | BeastMaster    |
|      35 |       12 | marksmanship   |
|      36 |       12 | Survival       |
+---------+----------+----------------+
```

classes table

```
+----------+-------------+
| class_id | class       |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | warlock     |
|        2 | priest      |
|        3 | paladin     |
|        4 | warrior     |
|        5 | mage        |
|        6 | demonhunter |
|        7 | druid       |
|        8 | shaman      |
|        9 | deathknight |
|       10 | rogue       |
|       11 | monk        |
|       12 | hunter      |
+----------+-------------+
```

players table

```
+-----------+--------------+
| player_id | name         |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 | Seranul      |
|         2 | Contherious  |
|         3 | Unicorns     |
|         4 | Remereili    |
|         5 | Affliction   |
|         6 | Meowing      |
|         7 | Brobot       |
|         8 | Bagelsbbq    |
|         9 | Rafusen      |
|        10 | Taiboku      |
|        11 | Yikes        |
|        12 | Thunderblaze |
|        13 | Muo          |
|        14 | Intz         |
|        15 | Trunks       |
|        16 | Kalphyte     |
|        17 | Eyeoftheshoe |
|        18 | Amuhnet      |
|        19 | Synkka       |
|        20 | Affliction   |
|        21 | Kts          |
|        22 | Shadowdreams |
|        23 | Zahel        |
|        24 | Azrama       |
|        25 | Seranul      |
|        26 | Momspaghetti |
|        27 | Ohki         |
|        28 | Rafusen      |
|        29 | Cindyy       |
|        30 | Grireaver    |
|        31 | Intz         |
|        32 | lazy         |
|        33 | missworld    |
|        34 | Affliction   |
|        35 | Amuhnet      |
|        36 | eyeoftheshoe |
|        37 | sanctus      |
|        38 | nozshelen    |
|        39 | Contherious  |
|        40 | messer       |
|        41 | catathor     |
|        42 | demonblaze   |
|        43 | wrillett     |
|        44 | raagnnar     |
|        45 | xizi         |
|        46 | nemesix      |
|        47 | zeroskill    |
|        48 | chikfillidan |
|        49 | tentenlol    |
|        50 | unicorns     |
|        51 | bubuhtide    |
|        52 | ohki         |
|        53 | azrama       |
+-----------+--------------+
```

players_classes table

```
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
| pc_id | class_id | player_id | spec_id |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
|     1 |        3 |         1 |       8 |
|     2 |       12 |         2 |      35 |
|     3 |        2 |         3 |       6 |
|     4 |       11 |         4 |      31 |
|     5 |        1 |         5 |       1 |
|     6 |       12 |         6 |      34 |
|     7 |        2 |         7 |       6 |
|     8 |       11 |         8 |      31 |
|     9 |        2 |         9 |       6 |
|    10 |        7 |        10 |      21 |
|    11 |        4 |        11 |      11 |
|    12 |        8 |        12 |      22 |
|    13 |        4 |        13 |      12 |
|    14 |        5 |        14 |      13 |
|    15 |        3 |        15 |       7 |
|    16 |       11 |        16 |      33 |
|    17 |        8 |        17 |      22 |
|    18 |        2 |        18 |       6 |
|    19 |        8 |        19 |      23 |
|    20 |       11 |        20 |      33 |
|    21 |        5 |        21 |      13 |
|    22 |        6 |        22 |      17 |
|    23 |       10 |        23 |      29 |
|    24 |        8 |        24 |      22 |
|    25 |       11 |        25 |      31 |
|    26 |       11 |        26 |      32 |
|    27 |        4 |        27 |      11 |
|    28 |        5 |        28 |      13 |
|    29 |        7 |        29 |      19 |
|    30 |        1 |        30 |       3 |
|    31 |        9 |        31 |      25 |
|    32 |        3 |        32 |       8 |
|    33 |        9 |        33 |      25 |
|    34 |        1 |        34 |       3 |
|    35 |        2 |        35 |       6 |
|    36 |        4 |        36 |      11 |
|    37 |        5 |        37 |      13 |
|    38 |        5 |        38 |      13 |
|    39 |        9 |        39 |      25 |
|    40 |        6 |        40 |      17 |
|    41 |       10 |        41 |      28 |
|    42 |        2 |        42 |       6 |
|    43 |        8 |        43 |      24 |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the relationship table in your query:

```
SELECT c.class, p.name, s.specialization
FROM players_classes pc
JOIN players p ON p.player_id = pc.player_id
JOIN classes c ON c.class_id = pc.class_id
JOIN specializations s ON s.spec_id = pc.spec_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8WTU9WpV9Mz6oF5vLANKP6/3)

You shouldn't even have `class_id` and `spec_id` in the other tables, since these are many-to-many relationships, and those columns can only be used for one-to-one relationships.

Comment: This does fully select the amount of names in the table, though it doesn't select the correct information when compared to a simple select * from players_classes

Comment: To add to this, it selects the correct NUMBER of names from the table, though there are duplicates of the names which contain incorrect information.

Comment: Each row of `players_classes` is supposed to represent a valid combination of player, class, and specialization. Of course you'll get duplicates, since this is a many-to-many relationship. The name will appear in each combination.

Comment: If you're getting incorrect information, it must be because you have incorrect rows in the `players_classes` table. Please add sample data and the expected results to the question.

Comment: I suspect you actually need two different relationship tables: `players_classes` and `classes_specializations`.

Comment: I added the edits you requested, let me know if you still think I need to restructure my tables or if there's a different way through only selects that this could be done. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Add the `players`, `classes`, and `specializations` tables. I can't tell where names like `paladin` and `seranul` are coming from.

Comment: Added pictures of the three tables, hopefully showing enough to be relevant

Comment: Please post text, not pictures. I can't paste pictures into a test database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192821/discussion-between-bynary-and-barmar).